# What is that nonsense string we get when requesting binary data, and how do we convert it into a proper buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-got

When using a library to request some non-ASCII/UTF8 data, we often get back a string full of nonsense. Example:

```
const got = require("got");
got("http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/16x16/1f525.png")
    .then(response => console.log(response.body))
```

This is the output:

```
�PNG

IHD��aaIDAT8�c`��L�fEb��?��8�-���@���5�!� ���|bQ\�$�� �ׁX�y�xT
���y@<                                                       �c�i��6$�K$
L÷���w��������_��Ϡ���d��?�j��2��� ��hX��cn������e"L����x�3�
             ��Y�f�N���
mt:����2e�f��N���~{'̀x�ȿ �;�m
                             �
    �PIEND�B`�            �vZ�]�dX<R�\�Y:������`�A�A��ӂƟ}�����#A�\�n����|�A� u83����,�{������@�@4��#��D�
```

Curiously, that is the same thing we see when downloading the image and using:

```
cat 1f525.png
```

What, exactly, is that string, why it looks like this, and how do we convert it to a proper Buffer object?

Comment: That you do not get a Buffer might be a problem of the `got` library or of the server. If the server tells the got library that the content is `text/*` then it might convert it to a string automatically.

Comment: @downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: Upload your file to https://hexed.it for a better view of that output :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a PNG image which is not text data, but just basic binary data. It doesn't make sense to interpret it as a string.

`got` will return `string`, `buffer`, `readableStream`, or `object`. `console.log` is converting your stream into a string which is not what you want. `cat` deals with text, not binary data.

Also the response from `http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/16x16/1f525.png` does not include the `Content-Type` header which could be throwing off the `got` library.

Comment: ... I know it is binary data. The point is exactly why I'm receiving a String instead of a Buffer, why that string looks like garbage when printed and, mostly, how do I get a proper buffer that can be saved to disk.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really strange that you see the same output from `cat` - that is how a PNG image looks like when interpreted as a string.

According to the `got` documentation, it should return a buffer when you specify the encoding as `null`. Perhaps `console.log` is converting the buffer to a string, or you could try to set the encoding to `image/png`.

Did you actually try to save to image to file? Perhaps it'll just work.

Comment: `According to the got documentation, it should return a buffer when you didn't specify an encoding. ` where did you read that? It seems like the default behavior is actually interpreting it as `utf-8`, which was the source of the confusion. Just saving doesn't work, indeed, because it was actually converted to a UTF-8 string. @RyanPlant proposes the correct solution in that case. Thanks in any case!

Comment: Indeed, my bad, the documentation says it's `utf-8` by default. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `got` will fetch you a string. It assumes you want UTF-8 text data by default, since that's probably the most common case, people fetching HTML documents. From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got):

> **`encoding`**
>
> Type: string, `null`
>
> Default: `'utf8'`
>
> Encoding to be used on `setEncoding` of the response data. If `null`, the body is returned as a `Buffer`.

If you want binary data instead, specify `{encoding: null}`:

```
const got = require("got");
got("http://twemoji.maxcdn.com/16x16/1f525.png", {encoding:null})
    .then(response => console.log(response.body))
```

Then `response.body` will be a `Buffer`.

Comment: That is the correct answer. `got` defaults to `utf-8` and that was my confusion. I'll accept this as soon as Stack Overflow allows me. This question is solved guys, please stop answering it! Thanks <3

Comment: @MaiaVictor i'm guessing if the response actually included the type, it wouldn't have done that.

Comment: @DanielA.White you mean the `content-type` header, right? I wonder if there is an online tool or something that allows me to inspect the response of a request.

Comment: I like the [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) Chrome extension for inspecting responses and crafting requests.